# How to bypass "Hostname was not verified" when using embeded mvn 3.2.1 on kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ssl

I have the following problem while trying to download the artifact bbb:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project phoenix-model: Could not
resolve dependencies for project
aaa:jar:4.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to
collect dependencies at
bbb:jar:1.0.24-SNAPSHOT: Failed to
read artifact descriptor for
bbb:jar:1.0.24-SNAPSHOT: Could not
transfer artifact
bbb:pom:1.0.24-SNAPSHOT from/to
nexus (https://s.s.com/nexus/content/groups/public):
Hostname 's.s.com' was not verified -    [Help 1]
```

it tries to connect to `s.s.com` (not the real name) but could not find it in the cacerts keystore since the site doesn't use the name `s.s.com` in it's certificate but rather `s.j.com` (and i can't change that since i'm not the admin).

Any way to tell maven or jdk to bypass that?

I am running the command from the eclipse m2 tool plugin by adding the following in the jdk arguments:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false  -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

currently using the embeded mvn of kepler which is at 3.2.1
any idea what is wrong?
if i used the same setting with the exception of mvn configured at external version 3.2.2 it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: There's no way fetching your dependencies without HTTPS? So, s.s.com does not provide this content over HTTP?

Comment: It its HTTPS only, you might make a dummy certificate for it.